# Does TDD require Unit Tests?

Tags: c#, java, php, unit-testing, tdd

Does Test Driven Development requires Unit Tests? I frequently find opinions that there is no TDD without Unit Test. I'm unable to confirm it with respected sources like Wiki or books I have access to.

From Wikipedia:

> Test-driven development (TDD) is a software development process that
>   relies on the repetition of a very short development cycle: first the
>   developer writes an (initially failing) automated test case that
>   defines a desired improvement or new function(...)

If Unit Test is not required does it mean creating integration test is enough to follow TDD?

Comment: Worry less about the name of process, and more about the techniques involved.  Unit tests and integration tests are both good things, regardless of what the overall paradigm is called.

Comment: Sometimes one have to worry about both

Comment: Ah, perhaps I misinterpreted your question (it seemed to be "can I avoid unit tests and still call it TDD?") ;)

Comment: It looks like you have. I'm gathering information about TDD. It's still very confusing subject.

Comment: Probably more suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the integration tests are meaningful and provide useful (and quick) feedback, then sure.  It's not about the purity of the testing paradigm, it's about the quick feedback loop and validation of the code being written.  As long as you have that, you have TDD.

On a side note, I wouldn't refer to Wikipedia as a respected resource in cases like this.  A source of reference material, sure.  But if you have questions about TDD, I doubt there's a more respected resource than [Kent Beck's book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530) on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your useful comment. With regards to the source I also looked into books I have access to and this research http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/ese/nagappan_tdd.pdf

Comment: ps. one of the reason why I find is confusing is "Three laws of TDD" . Each of them refer to "Unit Test".

Comment: @LukaszKujawa: Focus more on the spirit of the law than the letter of the law.  (Indeed, as the fiction referenced by "the three laws" demonstrated, laws are open to interpretation.)  Tests should be meaningful and should accurately validate the code.  They should be isolated and repeatable.  They should have no side-effects.  If this can all be accomplished by an integration test, great.  If it can be accomplished by testing via UI scripting, great.  As long as the value is there.

Answer (score -1):

When you are developing TDD, it is said that the best tests are atomic and isolated. This means that they are testing something very specific without depending of other stuff in your project. UnitTest is used exactly for this, so I guess that there is NO TDD without Unit Testing.

The idea in developing using TDD, is to provide yourself and the team with certainty that all your code is still working as it is supposed to. To achieve this you will need an integrated server where tests must run every time you integrate everything. If you made Unit Tests with a framework, this is easy to achieve.

I really recommend this book, it is short, easy to read, and really shows you the way:

[Test Driven: Practical TDD and Acceptance TDD for Java Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394850)